# Working in the console via exec.Command

Tags: go, console

Please help. I have to pass the console commando with a certain number of parameters. There are many.

That is, ideally, should be as follows:
test.go --distr 
For example:
test.go --distr mc curl cron

i create function

```
 func chroot_create() {
        cmd := exec.Command("urpmi",
                "--urpmi-root",
                *fldir,
                "--no-verify-rpm",
                "--nolock",
                "--auto",
                "--ignoresize",
                "--no-suggests",
                "basesystem-minimal",
                "rpm-build",
                "sudo",
                "urpmi",
                "curl")
        if err := cmd.Run(); err != nil {
                log.Println(err)
        }
}
```

And catch parameter distr through flag.Parse ()

How do I get rid of
                 "rpm-build",
                 "sudo",
                 "urpmi",
                 "curl")
That would not be tied to count packets. Please forgive me for stupidity, I'm just starting to learn golang. Especially when there was a problem.

Full code http://pastebin.com/yeuKy8Cc

Comment: Why do you want to get rid of them? Can't you just remove them from the invocation?

Comment: I want these options as you pass through the console. Or others. Few or one.
test.go -distr = mc, cron
That would not be binding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for the `...` operator.

```
func lsElements(elems ...string) {
        cmd := exec.Command("ls", append([]string{"-l", "-h", "/root"}, elems...)...)
        if err := cmd.Run(); err != nil {
                log.Println(err)
        }
}
```

You receive as function parameter `...string` which is in really a `[]string`, except that when you call the function, you pass the strings separately.

In order to use it, (and it works with any slices), you can "transform" your slice into list of element with `...` suffix.

In the case of exec, you could use `elem...` directly if you had only this. However, has you have fixed parameters as well, you need to build your slice with `append` and extend it back with `...`

Example: http://play.golang.org/p/180roQGL4a

Comment: It turns out this is what I need. Thank you, I will try to understand.

Comment: Looked at your code and try. It is impossible to do
`test.go -arch = i586 -dir = / tmp -repo = http: //tets.com/test mc, sudo, rpm-build`

The program is executed, but the packages **mc, sudo, rpm-build** is not established. So the parameters are not passed to the function

Comment: You would do `go run test.go -arch=i586 -dir=/tmp -repo=http://tets.com/test mc sudo rpm-build` (I updated the example on my answer)

Comment: And so I tried. Not thought to add `...`  `chrootCreate (* flDir, flag.Args ())`
and received an error
`can not use flag.Args () (type [] string)` as type string in function argument